# Что такое колоночная верстка?

Tags: html, css

Искал искал, но так и не нашел внятного объяснения, что за колоночные верстки?

3, 7, 12 колоночные...

Объясните поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вы имели ввиду использование сетки, типа "960 Grid"? Эта и подобные ей системы, позволяют быстро создать вёрстку основанную на сетке. Данный результат достигается при помощи протестированных на кроссбраузерность пресетов ширины страницы, куда вы помещаете свой код.
Подробнее тут - http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=926

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот пример простейшего грида:

3 колонки: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/bmta05rd/

5 колонок: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/bmta05rd/1/

7 колонок: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/bmta05rd/2/

```
.group {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background: #eee;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
.col + .col {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.size_3 .col {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.size_5 .col {
    width: 20%;
}
.size_7 .col {
    width: 14.28%;
}
```

А дальше на ваш вкус.
Конечно для создания колонок лучше всего использовать уже готовый грид (например из Bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит почитать про технологию [Twitter Bootstrap](http://bootstrap-ru.com/scaffolding.php#gridSystem), которая позволяет создавать довольно сложную структуру дизайна, используя обычные `div` и специальные классы.

Answer (score 0):

Колоночная верстка - это использование колонок для расположения элементов. Если колонок 12, это значит что ширина экрана (блока) условно делится на 12 равных частей и вы можете расположить свои элементы в каждой из этих ячеек, а также в нескольких сразу (объединить), т.е. отступы, ширина блоков будет кратна ширине 1 ячейки. Простейшую разметку можно сделать самому для тренировки, но для использования, как и написал ранее Дмитрий, рекомендую "Bootstrap". Это достаточно удобный фреймфорк для html, позволяющий делать красивые адаптивные странички и интерфейсы.